# IntelliJ IDEA, Test Runner Pane, maximize output pane

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to maximize the output pane of a test?
I can't believe that I have to endure the review process of the stacktrace in this narrow pane!

There is a shortcut (ctrl-shift-up) that make the pane grow a little. 
Does anybody know of a **shortcut** or a button to **maximize the pane**?
Like in eclipse for the output console (ctrl-m)
Anyway, Idea is great!

[image: output pane of Test Runner Pane]

Comment: I was hoping the responses would detail a way to maximize just the yellow block from the image, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<strike>It's not possible to maximize it, please vote for the corresponding feature request:</strike>

- [IDEA-64469](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64469) Provide a way to view test console output maximized (like double-clicking it?)

### Update

It has been implemented as described in the issue:

> You can maximize/restore tool window size:
>
> - With double-click on toolwindow header
> - With shortcut Shift+Ctrl+' (Shift+Command+' for Mac OS X)
> - Via "Resize" actions group (see popup menu for tool window)

Comment: Oh, my, the issue was created on 21 Jan 2011: we have no hope!! o_O

Comment: It has been developed! so checkout the current version and the last comment

Comment: I can seem to make the double click work (Oct 2018), but resize works at least

Answer (score 11):

- On Linux and Windows:<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Quote(')</kbd>

  On Mac:<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Quote(')</kbd>
- With double-click on toolwindow header
- Via "Resize" actions group (see popup menu for tool window)

Tested on 2016.1.1(Linux) & 2018.1.1(Linux).
[image: Maximize Tool Window]

On my AZERTY keyboad I had to reassign the shortcut to Alt + M and Alt + W (maximize window).
It was maybe not yet implemented in 2013.

Answer (score 5):

Look in Settings -> Keymap

Inside of that, look for "Maximize tool window" item.
Use the assigned shortcut or set one of your preference.

Regards

Comment: Tested on idea 2016.1.1 and it is exaclty the correct answer  to the question. <BR>Was maybe not implemented in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + Quote shortcut you have to activate the Run/Debug Command Output window, which in my keyboard is Right/Alt + 4 or , Right/Alt + 5 ...